# P value and sample size relationship

Tags: sample, power-analysis, p-lang

Say for a 2x2 experiment, the power analysis said the sample size should be over 1000 to detect 0.1 effect size. Right now, with the sample size of below 100, the effect size of .12 is insignificant with the p value being 0.8 (very far from .05)

Is it fair to say even I attain the required over 1000 sample, the result is less likely to be significant?

I try nothing as this is a statistic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to ask this question on Cross Validated, the stats site of stackoverflow: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

From my point of view: When the p-value is too large for a sample size of 100, this might be because of lots of variance in the random variable. This is probably (haha) also why your power analysis suggested to draw 1000 samples. So unless the cost of drawing 1000 samples is prohibitively high, I'd go with 1000 samples instead of 100.